# Selective HDMI Audio

Tags: 13.04, sound, hdmi

Is it possible to have some programs use HDMI audio out, and others use internal speakers?

Specifically, I am trying to have VLC & RhythmBox use HDMI audio, and all other applications use internal speakers.

Ubuntu 13.04, running on a Lenovo Y500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard audio settings dialog only allows to change the output device for all applications. But there is (or has been, depending on perspective) an alternative. Pulseaudio, the sound server used with Ubuntu, comes with its own volume setting tool called `pavucontrol`. It isn't installed by default any longer, but you can just install it yourself from the standard repositories.

Pavucontrol allows you not only to control the volume of any application currently playing sound independently, but you can also control to which of the available output devices the applications sound is "routed". So you can have your video players' sound on HDMI, your VoIP phone apps sound on your headset, your radio apps sound on your stereo (provided it is a PulseAudio sink) and so forth.